# Even Schwartz function which is $\geq 1$ on the unit ball and whose Fourier transform is compactly supported

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why does there exist an even Schwartz function $\phi$ such that $\phi \geq 1$ on the unit ball and the Fourier transform of $\phi$ is compactly supported?

I've been think of taking $f = e^{-\frac{1}{|x|^{2} -1}}1_{|x| < 1}$ and $\phi = |\widehat{f}|^{2} = \widehat{f}\bar{\widehat{f}}$. Then $\hat{\phi} = f \ast \tilde{\bar{f}}$ where $\tilde{g}(x) = g(-x)$. Then I think $g$ should be compactly supported since both $f$ and $\tilde{\bar{f}}$ are. As $\phi$ is nonnegative, it cannot be zero everywhere, so there's some ball $B(x_{0}, r)$ for which $\phi$ is $> 0$. How can I guarantee that this ball is the unit ball? I imagine I need to rescale things but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Hmm, that $f$ is actually $C^\infty$? Very clever. Anyway, you can make a change of variables: If $\delta>0$ and $h(x)=f(\delta x)$ then $\hat h(\xi)=\delta^{-n}\hat f(\xi/\delta)$. Or something like that...

Comment: Isn't your choice of $f$ contradict the fact that a function and its fourier transform cannot both be compactly supported?