# Schwartz function whose Fourier transform is compactly supported and $\geq 1$ on the unit ball.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

I need to construct such a function but the closest I have come to is to take $f(t) = e^{-|t|}, t\in\Bbb{R^d}$. But its Fourier transform is not compactly supported as is $\hat{f}(x) = \frac{2}{1+x^2}$.

[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506368/even-schwartz-function-which-is-geq-1-on-the-unit-ball-and-whose-fourier-tran?rq=1) question is closely related, but the requirement of the function is reversed.

Comment: impossible. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672832/how-do-you-prove-that-a-function-f-in-l1-bf-r-and-its-fourier-transform-c/1672839#1672839

Comment: why not? $e^{-|t|}$ is not decreasing faster than the Gaussian?

Comment: a compactly supported function is. and you can consider $\hat{g}\in L^1$, and multiply it by the indicator function of a ball containing your compact support, this way you will convoluate $g$ by the sinus cardinal in dimension $d$, and hence it won't be a rapidly  decreasing function

Comment: hence I'd say the best you can reach if $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported is $f(x)$ decreasing as $x^{-d}$ (decreasing as fast as the sinus cardinal (= ideal filter) in dimension $d$

Comment: But my understanding of the uncertainty principle was that the function and its fourier transforms cannot both be decaying faster than the Gaussian.

Comment: ??? you said $f$ is a Schwartz function, hence it is rapidly decreasing, and you said $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported, hence it is decreasing MUCH faster than the gaussian.

Comment: did you understand my argument with the fact that if $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported, then $f$ is an ideal filter ? (removing all the frequencies $> \omega_0$) hence it is a filtered version of the sinus cardinal, and hence it is decreasing when $|t| \to \infty$ as fast as the sinus cardinal

Comment: What on earth is a sinus cardinal? Also, I don't see the issue. The Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is still a Schwartz function.

Comment: So just to be clear, $f(t) = e^{-|t|}$ decays faster than any negative exponentials but not in the Schwartz space?

Comment: Do you want $f$ such that $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported and $f\ge 1$ in the unit ball? Take a smooth function $g$ supported in a small enough ball and define $f = C|\hat{g}|^2$, for some appropriate constant $C$. By the way, $e^{-|t|}$ is not smooth, so it isn't Schwarz. Good luck!

Comment: @carmichael561 : the ideal filter, $sinc(t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$ whose Fourier transform is $1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(\xi)$, and its generalization in dimension $d$, this is because dezdichado asked for a compactly supported Fourier transform.

Answer (score 4):

Take any nontrivial, nonnegative, symmetric function $g \in C_c^\infty (\Bbb{R}^d)$. If we let $h := \mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$, then $h$ is real-valued (why?) and
$$
h(0) = \int g(x) \, dx > 0,
$$
since $g \geq 0$ and $g \not \equiv 0$.

By continuity of $h$ and by rescaling (i.e., replace $g$ by $Cg$ for some large $C>1$), we get $h \geq 1$ on $B_{2\delta} (0)$ for some $\delta > 0$.

Now, finally take $f : x \mapsto h(\delta \cdot x)$. It is not hard to see $f \geq 1$ on $B_1 (0)$ and
$$
\widehat{f} = \delta^{-d} \cdot  \widehat{h}(\cdot / \delta)  \in C_c^\infty,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got everything except why $\hat{h}$ is compactly supported. Somehow I fail to see this from its construction.

Comment: @dezdichado: Because $\hat {h}=g $.

Comment: of course. stupid me.